# Accessing archive in the middle of a Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I used `archiveArtifacts` to archive some outputs that need to be validated manually before finishing the job. But it seems that the archive is not accessible in the middle of the job. I was wondering if there is anyway that I can get access to archive before the job is done?

Comment: It should still be in your workspace. Access it directly.

Comment: @IanW I know. But there are tones of files in the workspace. I just want to cherry pick a couple of them.